# std::unique_ptr and reset() or a Reset method for your class?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, class-design, unique-ptr

With `std::unique_ptr::reset`, you can easily bring your instance back to a fresh state.

Pre-C++11, to achieve similar behavior, I have seen a lot of classes define a `Reset()` method that resets all its internal members. But now, I think the same could be accomplished with just a constructor and destructor and `reset`ing the `unique_ptr` to a new instance of the class. Are there any benefits I'm missing for why you would still prefer a `Reset()` method, or should we always just use a `unique_ptr` and `reset` it to a new instance whenever we want to "reset" our class?

The only benefit I can think of is that you save an allocation/deletion which can sometimes be expensive.
The cost of course is the complexity of maintaining a Reset() function and making sure that it stays up to date with other code changes.

Is that it? It's just a complexity v. performance question?

Comment: What if you want to allocate your object on the stack?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a really nice generic way to reset the state your class to its default constructed state:

```
// Previously constructed MyClass myvalue = ...
myvalue = MyClass{};
```

This involves two operations:

1. Default construction.
2. Move assignment.

Ideally both of these should be dirt cheap.

Comment: Three operations?:
1. Default construction.
2. Destruction of `myvalue`.
3. Move assignment.

Comment: Could we somehow skip the move assignment and get the compiler just to destruct and construct the class in place?
I would never write this, but something like `MyClass::~MyClass(&myvalue); new (&myvalue) MyClass;`

Answer (score 0):

> The only benefit I can think of is that you save an
>   allocation/deletion which can sometimes be expensive

Not only allocation that *might* be expensive, but also possible memory fragmentation, bad locality (thanks to @Cris for term that was searching in my mind) ,  during frequent resets, will eventually introduce huge performance problems.

`unique_ptr` is not meant at all to reset your instance state.
 `unique_ptr::reset` resets the *ownership* of the `unique_ptr`, which is *in consequence* call destructor on "old" instance.

So this is completely different from your instance `Reset` method.

In case of Reset

- you don't instantiate a new memory -> pro
- potentially can reuse the same memory without trashing it, so keep your data aligned and tightly packed(depends on *how* you implment your `Reset` method) -> pro
- non secure memory management, leading to mem leaks -> cons

In case of `unique_ptr`

- no pointer aliasing and memory management control -> pro
- allocation of a new instance every time -> cons

All *pros* and *cons* are naturally arguable, depends on concrete implementation and actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The allocation/deletion is one cost but there is also the cost of an extra level of indirection to access the object via pointer. E.g poorer data locality.

A `Reset()` function can also be called in contexts where you only have a reference or pointer. The only object that should be aware that an object is being managed by a `unique_ptr` is the owner. In other contexts it is better to use a reference or pointer.

But as long as you are aware of the costs and only the owner wants to do a reset, I don't see anything wrong with doing this.

Of course this is not new in C++11, it's always been possible to do this with heap allocated objects. This is just one example of how `unique_ptr` makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up things here.

`unique_ptr` like `shared_ptr` is a construct to represent ownership.
Using `unique_ptr` would mean that your classes can neither be copied nor copy assigned to unless you provide a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator yourself.
This would be additional work though.

So if you still want to provide a reset method but do not want to hand code resetting each member variable you could do something like this:

```
MyClass::Reset()
{
    this->~MyClass();
    new(this) MyClass();
}
```

which would reset your instance to its default created state.

Disadvantages of such an approach are

- Not exception save, so if your constructor can throw you will have problems.
- Dynamic memory your members use internally is thrown away and not reused directly. For example a `vector` member and its associated memory on the heap are freed instead of reused.

In fact you could also implement `Reset` like

```
MyClass::Reset()
{
    *this = MyClass();
}
```

though that could be slower than the previous solution.